# db prepare insert into multiple databases

Tags: php, mysql, database

Is there a way to insert values into multiple databases using db prepare?
I use following code to insert in one database:

```
$insert_stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO database(name) VALUES(:name)");
```

I would like to insert a value into another database in the same rule, but this does not work, par example:

```
$insert_stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO database(name) VALUES(:name") INSERT INTO example(street) VALUES (:street)");
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with running two separate queries through two separate prepared statements.

Comment: *but this does not work* Excess dquote and lost delimiter. `$insert_stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO database(name) VALUES(:name); INSERT INTO example(street) VALUES (:street);");`. And ensure that multi-queries are allowed and enabled. PS. Do not confuse the terms "database" and "table".

Comment: Are you sure you're using the term "database" correctly? Everything in the question, save for the exact words, imply you mean tables.

Answer (score 0):

you can't use db object name as parameter in sql  the only way for to somethings equivalent is so called  "dynamic sql" .

sql string builded dynamically

```
$name =  'my_table_name";
$insert_stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO database" . $name . "(col1, col2, col3)  
                         VALUES(:param1, :param2, :param3) ;";"
```

anyway be careful using php var in sql  .. provide always a proper sanitize for avoid risk of sqlinjection